# Without Refreshing the Page Data is not Updating in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am fetching the data from firebase in reactjs. The issue i am facing is without refreshing the page data is not getting update.

As you can see in below screenshot, i showing data in a table there i am showing edit button and by clicking on it i am updating the data. Data successfully getting update in firebase but here in the page it is not getting update till i do not refresh the page.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**fetching the data:**

```
const [activityproduct,setActvityProduct] =useState([])

useEffect(() => {

  let isMounted = true;

  const doFetch = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(dbname, "tablename"));  
    const arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
      
      if (isMounted) setActvityProduct(arr);       
    });         
  };   
    
    doFetch()     
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!isMounted) return;       
      console.error("failed to fetch data", err);
    });

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

**updating the data:**

```
const handleUpdate =async()=>{
  const updateData = doc(dbname,"tablename",id)
  await updateDoc(updateData,{name1:title})
  setTitle("")
}
```

**Here showing the data:**

```
{
    activityproduct.map(values=>
      <tr key={values.id} id={values.id}>                
        <td>{values.name1} </td>
        <td>  <button className='btn' onClick={()=>handleEdit(values.id,values.name1)}> Edit </button>    </td>
      </tr>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're calling `getDocs`, which reads the data once only. If you want to listen for updates: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @Frank Van Puffelen

> You're calling getDocs, which reads the data once only. If you want to listen for updates: [firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen](http://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution. Thanks to Frank and Mara also.

**This is working for me:**

```
    useEffect(() => {

    const listenDemoTbl = () => {   
        onSnapshot(collection(dbname, "tablename"), (snapshot) => {
            setProduct(snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))            
        })  
    }
    
    listenDemoTbl();
    

}, []);
```